# CodeIgniter Directory Helper Show Only Folders

Tags: php, codeigniter, directory, helper

The Directory Helper - directory_map lists out folders and files in an array. Which is great but not exactly what I want. Is there a way to list out only the folders? And skip over the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the name suggests it is a directory mapper - maps everything. It takes three args, one is the path, the second is the subfolder depth and the third is whether hidden files/folders need to be shown.

What you can do is just iterate the array provided by the helper and do an `if is_dir()` before listing. Just add a simple function to your custom helper.